# Remove part of the URL in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, userscripts

I am using Jquery userscript to change the link within `<iframe>` or `<a>` with any other link for me (not on the site). How can I remove part of that link?

Currently this userscripts turns

**http://www.youtube.com/embed/YDkTCGL1l0s?hd=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&wmode=opaque&cc_load_policy=1&rel=0&autoplay=1**

into

**http://playit.pk/embed?v=YDkTCGL1l0s%3fhd=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&wmode=opaque&cc_load_policy=1&rel=0&autoplay=1**

I want to remove the

**hd=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&wmode=opaque&cc_load_policy=1&rel=0&autoplay=1**

So that the final link becomes

**http://playit.pk/embed?v=YDkTCGL1l0s**

Here is what I am currently using.

```
$('iframe').each(function(){
        this.src = this.src.replace('youtube.com/embed/', 'playit.pk/embed?v=');
    });
```

Comment: so it's not working or you want another way?

Comment: Basically when it is converted to another link

http://playit.pk/embed?v=YDkTCGL1l0s%3fhd=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&wmode=opaque&cc_load_policy=1&rel=0&autoplay=1

As no such link exist on `playit.pk` so the video wont start.  So only if the link is like

http://playit.pk/embed?v=YDkTCGL1l0s

The video starts playing

Comment: I think you are trying to encode/decode the url here.

Comment: So what do you want me to? Wait for the comments like "please elaborate :p"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('iframe').each(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        var index = src.indexOf('?');
            src = src.substring(0,index);

        $(this).attr('src',src.replace('youtube.com/embed/', 'playit.pk/embed?v='));
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7g6w2/)**